# referential integrity constraint violation occurred using fluentAPI (EF)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Using EF in a WPF project.

I have 2 entities as follows:

```
public class Entity1
{
...
public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
...
}


public class Entity2
{
...
public virtual Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
...
}
```

The association is set this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>().HasRequired(r => r.Entity2).WithOptional(s => s.entity1);
```

Here my sample:

```
//TESTCODE
Entity1 entity1=new Entity1(){Name="test"};
Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
entity1.Entity2=Entity2;
Entity2 entity2=new Entity2();

Context context = new Context();
context.Entities1.Add(entity1);
context.SaveChanges();//OK


#regionpart1
context.Entities2.Remove(entity1.Entity2);
context.SaveChanges();//NEEDED!!!
#endregion

entity1.Entity2=entity2;
entity1.Entity2.entity1=entity1;
context.SaveChanges(); //halts without region part1!!
```

Why does it halt if I do not remove the part1 region 3 lines?

I suppose I am missing a method to pipe into the fluent API part so that I do not need to explicitally remove the old entity1.Entity2 object before I can set a new value?

The exception I got is:
 {"A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'T_Entity2.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) 
 of 'T_Entity1.Id' on the other end."

Thx in advance and I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Can you show how your new Entity2 gets created? Meaning the second instance which is assigned to entity1.Entity2 at the end of your code snippet.

Comment: Very sorry for the poor formatting of the original post. I see that most of the space characters had vanished. I have just rewritten it again hoping it will be a bit more clear.
Now you should see that the second Entiity2 instance is created at the begining of the sample (as the 1st one).